# Configure Kubernetes with docker container on Ubuntu VM

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, dockerfile

I am using the `YAML` file to deploy the container on `Kubernetes` with some replication factor on a hosted machine.

## YAML File

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mojo-deployment
  labels:
    app: mojo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mojo
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mojo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mojo
          image: mojo:1.0.1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9000

---
#Services Info
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mojo-services
spec:
  selector:
    app: mojo
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376

---

#Ingress Configuration
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mojo-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: mojo
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: mojo-services
    servicePort: 80
```

Steps:

1. Build `Docker` image using `docker build -t mojo:1.0 .
2. `docker image ls` show me an image id.
3. Skipping `docker build` command to deploy image on container. Do I need to do it? or `kubectl` service will take care of it.
4. Run `kubectl apply -f Prod.yaml`. It shows

> deployment.apps/mojo-deployment created
>
> service/mojo-services created
>
> ingress.networking.k8s.io/mojo-ingress created

5. `kubectl get service` returns

   [image]
6. `kubectl get pod` returns
   [image]
7. `kubectl get deployment` returns
   [image]

Questions?

1. Do I need to build the container before deploying `YAML` file? I tried it but still `kubernetes` not running.
2. Why all pods are showing `Pending` status.
3. Deployment is also showing `pending` status.
4. Though I am trying to access the `Ingress` with :80 and cannot access it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to push your image in a registry in order to get the deployment working. Kubernetes does not deal with images (i.e. building, pushing...).

Try `kubectl describe deployment mojo-deployment`, you'll get more informations about why it's pending (surely because it does not know how to get your Docker image).

Answer (score 1):

Your questions in order:

1. The container not only need to be built, it needs to be in a registry that Kubernetes has access to.  If you are using Docker containers (the default), you can push your container to [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) so that Kubernetes can retrieve the image.
2. They are showing as pending because they do not yet have any containers inside of them.  You've described in the YAML that you want the container in the pod, but Kubernetes has not yet built a working Pod to your specification.
3. The deployment is pending because Kubernetes has not yet been able to create the 3 desired pods.
4. [Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) in Kubernetes are independent of Pods.  This is why the services are shown as available.  So internally, Kubernetes is routing your request to port 80 in the cluster, but no services are yet available on that port.